# Check if a single value in List in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmatrix

How to check a single value is in a List.  My List contains few random numbers: `13, 55, 34, 122, 322, 2132, 4345, 3000`.

I want to have a bool check the list if it contains int 4 or any other number.  List can have large numbers in three or four figures in the list.

It would be nice to guide me to design helper in webmatrix to provide bool results for this value check.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you heard of the instance method `List.Contains()`?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.  You'll have more success getting an answer if you demonstrate some specific code, particularly something you've already tried.

Comment: You could have tried google, you know..! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,intVariable is your variable to search

```
bool isInList = intList.IndexOf(intVariable) != -1;
```

Comment: It didn't work for me or I was not implementing correctly. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get away without iteration (loop). Use [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)(that uses iterator internally) for simplicity.

```
var ints = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
var any5 = ints.Any( i=> i== 5);
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? I have checked the query before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

if the list is not that big why dont you loop inside the list

```
foreach(int a in MyList)
{
   if(a == "that_value")
   {
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I am already doing through loop; some what similar to this. Thanks.

Comment: I think there should be some other method to call this procedure through web helper in web matrix rather than putting this kind of loop over different places.